# combined use of geom_boxplot and scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use `geom_boxplot` and rescale my axis with `scale_x_datetime` at the same time. However `geom_boxplot` requires a `factor` as an input, while `scale_x_datetime` will only accept class `POSIXct`. 
Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dates <- c("02/27/92", "02/27/92")
times <- c("20:03:20", "22:29:56")
x <- paste(dates, times)
x <- strptime(x, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
test = cbind(data.frame(rep(x, 20)), rnorm(40))
names(test)=c("a", "b")
plot1 = ggplot(test) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(a), y=b))
plot1
plot2 = plot1 + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"))
plot2
```

plot1 will be fine but the last line casts me the error:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

however that is not an option for `geom_boxplot` which will execute with an undesired result if the x-value is not a factor:

```
ggplot(test) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=a, y=b))
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Desired result: I want to have a label for the first time only (in the format e.g. `"%H%M"`) and no label for the second point in time.

Comment: I suspect that `scale_x_datetime`  is expecting the x variable to be continuous or date and that a factor is not satisfying that expectation. Try to change the format of the labels rather than applying an inappropriate scale.

Comment: @BondedDust true, as the error says is expects a `POSIXct` variable, but `geom_boxplot` already forces me to use a `factor`.

Comment: Right, so go find a ggplot2 formatting function instead of `scale_x_datetime`. Looking at the Index of the package I'd look at `?guides`.

Comment: I don't see how `guides` will help me in this (but correct me if I wrong). However you have a point with suggestion a ggplot2 formatting function so the next best best guess is `scale_x_continuous`. I try supplying both a factor and POSIXct values as `breaks` but in both cases I get the error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as I expected. (You never did say how you expected.)

```
plot2 = plot1 + scale_x_discrete(labels=format.Date(x, "%Y/%m/%d %H"))
plot2
```

The  point here is that you created an x-factor variable by using: `aes(x=factor(a), y=b)` so any label formatting needs to respect the mode of the x-variable. I don't use ggplot2 because its widespread non-standard evaluation and code hiding drives me nuts, but I do think in terms of the basic modes and classes of R objects.

Comment: This does the trick! I have edited to specify the desired result and it can be achieved with the following line `plot2 = plot1 + scale_x_discrete(labels=c(format.Date(x[1], "%H:%M"), ""))` Thank you!