# Additional time-scale with scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this:

```
        Date Timestamp        xAcc        yAcc       zAcc
17:42:20.361   1866703 -0.03526625 -0.01266312 -0.9679290
17:42:20.381   1866713 -0.02735012 -0.02082901 -0.9759240
17:42:20.381   1866723 -0.05109851 -0.01674607 -0.9599340
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, to plot *Timestamp* against e.g. *xAcc*, but with the real time in seconds on the x-scale, starting with 0.

```
diff = as.difftime("00:00:00.010001", "%H:%M:%OS")
start = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000", "", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
DF$Date = seq.POSIXt(start, by=diff, length.out=length(DF$Date))

ggplot(DF, aes(Timestamp, xAcc)) +
     geom_line() +
     labs(x = 't') +
     scale_x_datetime(labels = DF$Date)
```

But then I get this:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

Which I find strange, since ?seq.POSIXt says

> **Value** A vector of class "POSIXct".

Does the problem have something to do with

```
> class(DF$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I found a similar question there [combined use of geom_boxplot and scale_x_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791035/combined-use-of-geom-boxplot-and-scale-x-datetime) and tried different variations of

```
... + scale_x_discrete(labels = format.Date(DF$Date, "%S"))
```

But then there's no scale at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map `Date`, which is `POSIXct`, to `x`.

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2017-11-14

library(ggplot2)

DF <- read.table(text = "        Date Timestamp        xAcc        yAcc       zAcc
17:42:20.361   1866703 -0.03526625 -0.01266312 -0.9679290
17:42:20.381   1866713 -0.02735012 -0.02082901 -0.9759240
17:42:20.381   1866723 -0.05109851 -0.01674607 -0.9599340", header = TRUE)

diff <- as.difftime("00:00:00.010001", "%H:%M:%OS")
start <- as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000", "", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
DF$Date <- seq.POSIXt(start, by=diff, length.out=length(DF$Date))

p <- ggplot(DF, aes(Date, xAcc)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = 't')
p
```

[image]

If you want more control on breaks and labels, you can specify them on `scale_x_datetime()`:

```r
p +  scale_x_datetime(breaks = DF$Date, labels = DF$Date)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know that I could just plot Date against xAcc, but I have a reason to use Timestamp. The actual question was, how to get rid of that error when using scale_x_datetime or an alternative.

Comment: Ah, sorry... Anyway, I meant to say you need to convert the column for `x` (either it is `Timestamp` or `Date`) to `POSIXct` if you want to use `scale_x_datetime()`. Or, if you really want to avoid `POSIXct`, specifiing `breaks` may be good. (e.g. `scale_x_continuous(breaks = DF$Timestamp, labels = format.Date(DF$Date, "%S"))`)